# Multi-line strings in objective-c localized strings file

Tags: objective-c, iphone, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have a template for an email that I've put in a localized strings file, and I'm loading the string with the `NSLocalizedString` macro.

I'd rather not make each line its own string with a unique key. In Objective-C, I can create a human-readable multiline string like so:

```
NSString *email = @"Hello %@,\n"
    "\n"
    "Check out %@.\n"
    "\n"
    "Sincerely,\n"
    "\n"
    "%@";
```

I tried to put that in a .strings file with:

```
"email" = "Hello %@,\n"
    "\n"
    "Check out %@.\n"
    "\n"
    "Sincerely,\n"
    "\n"
    "%@";
```

But I get the following error at build time:

```
CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary.
email-template.strings: Unexpected character " at line 1
Command /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copystrings failed with exit code 1
```

I can concatenate it all together like this:

```
"email" = "Hello %@,\n\nCheck out %@.\n\nSincerely,\n\n%@";
```

But that will be a mess to maintain, particularly as the email gets longer.

Is there a way to do this in a localized strings file? I've already tried adding backslashes at the end of each line, to no avail.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Just use the new lines directly.

```
"email" = "Hello %@,

Check out %@.

Sincerely,

%@";
```

Comment: But then, the colors of the text editor won't show correctly (the string is not completely in one color)

Comment: The string does seem to be completely in one colour these days :)