# iOS: Localise multi-line string literals

Tags: ios, swift, string, localization

Since a recent swift version, multi line string literals are available that allow to format the appearance of a multi line string easily.

I'm looking for a way, though, to localise such a string.

Here is an example of the text of a pre-configured mail, that users can send:

```
mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("""
                              Hi,

                               I would like to share the following feedback:

                              """,
                              isHTML: false)
```

It seems there is no way to properly transform this into the localisable .strings file.

As a workaround, I came up with the solution to individually localise each part of the message and use interpolation:

```
let localisedGreeting = NSLocalizedString("Hi", comment: "")
let localisedMessage = NSLocalizedString("I would like to share the following feedback: ", comment: "")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("""
                                  \(localisedGreeting),

                                   \(localisedMessage)

                                  """,
                                  isHTML: false)
```

The .strings file looks like this:

```
"Hi" = "Hallo";
"I would like to share the following feedback: " = "ich möchte folgendes Feedback geben: ";
```

Is there a better/more concise way to do this?

Comment: The *value* in Localizable.strings could always be multiline (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2968662/1187415) – why do you want the *key* to be multiline?

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR, that's interesting. I always thought the exact string would be looked up. I've used the base language (English) string as a key always. If I changed it to work as you suggested I'd need to set up a dedicated .strings file for English as well, correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @nontomatic i think if it's a localized 1 string then it won't make difference if it's \\n or written multiline

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to give a max stripped down example, but I was looking for a solution that would work comfortably with any multi line string literal and also with custom indentation.

Comment: Aside bar note: I would suggest to use a short text for keys instead of the fully translation for the value, it would be tedious for when using it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both keys and values in the `Localizable.strings` file can be multi-line.
With

```
"Hi,

 I would like to share the following feedback:
" = "Hallo,

 ich möchte folgendes Feedback geben:
";
```

the call

```
let localizedMessage = NSLocalizedString("""
                      Hi,

                       I would like to share the following feedback:

                      """, comment: "")
```

expands as intended.

This might however not work with localization tools, and also does not
display with the correct syntax coloring in the Localizable.strings, which
might be confusing.

I would use a short (single-line) key instead, and localize that for all
languages (including the default language english).

Answer (score 0):

For me this layout of text and quotes worked (Swift 5.3, Xcode 12)

Localizable.strings

```
"First Line
Second Line" = "Erste Linie
Zweite Linie";
```

Implementation

```
let lines = NSLocalizedString("""
            First Line
            Second Line
""", comment: "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create multiline strings directly in a single line using `" "` and these character literals:

- Use `\n` to break the line.
- Use `\n\n` to break the line and create a blank line.

A string in Swift file:

```
let longString: localizedStringKey = "This is the first line.\n\nThis is the second line after the blank line."
```

Then the string created above can be used in `Localizable.strings` like this:

```
"This is the first line.\n\nThis is the second line." = "This is the first line.\n\nThis is the second line after the blank line.";
```

*Tested on Xcode 15, Swift 5, SwiftUI on iOS 17*