# How can I localise my multiple string in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string, localization, multiline

When I do as below, I can write all string expressions in different languages. But it doesn't happen when I make a multi line String. Please help me on how to Integrate this?

Modal

```
Unit(unit: "Unit 1".localized(),
             category: [Category(category: "Personal Pronouns".localized()])
```

controller

```
extension String {
    func localized() -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self,
                                 tableName: "Localizable",
                                 bundle: .main,
                                 value: self,
                                 comment: self)
    }      
}
```

localizable.string

```
"Unit 1" = "Unité 1";
"Personal Pronouns" = "Pronoms personnel";
```

The multi line string I want to do will be like this but how ?

```
let text = """
    We want to change the World
    but not everywhere or everything
    only on people 
        """
```

https://github.com/ysrtirak/Make-localise
here there is my example

I could not translate the text in """ """

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but according to [**this SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968650/multi-line-strings-in-objective-c-localized-strings-file) you can put multi-line strings directly into your localizable.strings file:

localizable.strings:

```
"multiLine" = "We want to change the World
but not everywhere or everything
only on people";
```

And in your swift code:

```
print("multiLine".localized())
```

I just tried a test application, and the following localizable.strings file worked perfectly:

```
/* 
  Localizable.strings
  MultiLine

  Created by Duncan Champney on 8/13/21.
  
*/
"foo" = "This
is
a
multi-line
string";
```

With that localizable.strings file, this code:

```
        print(NSLocalizedString("foo", value: "foo", comment: "comment"))
```

prints the output:

```
This
is
a
multi-line
string
```

Just as you would expect it to.

### Edit:

Try downloading [**this sample app**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/MultiLine.git) from Github. It is a working example of using multi-line strings in a localizable.strings file.

### Edit #2:

You have an extra newline at the beginning and end of the English in your French localizable.strings. Change it as follows:

```
/* 
  Localizable.strings
  Make localise

  Created by Yasir Tırak on 15.08.2021.
  
*/

"I know how to localise that . thats not problem" = "Je sais comment localiser ça. ce n'est pas un problème";
"This is my text
But i cant localise it
hey
how are you" = "C'est mon texte
Mais je ne peux pas le localiser
Hé
Comment ça va";
```

That works.

To figure out what was going on, I broke your code into steps and logged the results:

```
 let text = """
 This is my text
 But i cant localise it
 hey
 how are you
 """
 print("text = '\(text)'")
 let localizedText = text.localized()
 textLabel.text = localizedText
```

That outputs:

```
text = 'This is my text
But i cant localise it
hey
how are you'
```

Note how there are no newlines before the first single quote and none after the last single quote.

Comment: No, I tried this, but Objective-c does not accept a multi-line text in this way, it gives an error.  Even swift code does not accept multi-line for plain string expression in this way, it is necessary to put 3 quotation marks.

Comment: The strings file is not Objective-C. It's a very specific C-like syntax.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but the system definitely does not accept this. I tried and your solution is not working.

Comment: I just tested it with the localizable.strings file I added to my answer and it most definitely works.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I just posted a link to a working project on Github that uses a multi-line localizable.strings file.

Comment: no you understood wrong sir, normally I have modal to put tableView for every section, Already I have multiple line texts with """text""" but when I want to localise it is not working because my string value is not "text" , it is already """text"""

Comment: Upload an example project with this problem to to github and add a link to it in your question.

Comment: I am able to include multi-line localized strings in a project's localizable.strings file. I'm not sure what you mean when you say that your string is "already """text"""." You can enclose a multi-line string literal in 3 pairs of double quotes, but it sounds like you might be mis-using that. Post a minimal project that shows this error and then we can help you sort it out.

Comment: I added an example please check it and give your idea.